# Redirecting back into my website from thirdparty site in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need help here.
I'm trying to integrate a Payment gateway(VoguePay) in my app. Now the sandbox testing tested good on payment but the problem is getting the "success_url" to work. How do I go about this!

```
<form method="POST" action="https://voguepay.com/pay/">
<input type="hidden" name="v_merchant_id" value="demo"/>
<input type='hidden' name='notify_url' value="{{url('notification')}}" />
<input type='hidden' name='success_url' value="{{url('transaction/successful')}}" />
<input type='hidden' name='fail_url' value="{{url('transaction/fail')}}" />
<input type='submit'  value='Buy now' />
</form>
```

This what laravel is saying when Voguepay is getting a hand on 'success_url'
 "Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message"

Thank you in advance

Edited

web.php

Route::post('notification','VoguepayController@notify')->name('notification');
    Route::get('transaction/successful','VoguepayController@success')->name('success');
    Route::get('transaction/fail', 'VoguepayController@fail')->name('fail');

Comment: please show your `web.php` or `routes.php`.

Comment: Did you define the success-url-route? Seems like it may be posting to your page instead of get.

Comment: share your route also `transaction/successful` ?

Comment: Guys check my edited question

Comment: Your `transaction/successful` is a `GET` request and your form is `POST`. That's the reason why you have `MethodNotAllowed` exception. You're trying to access a `GET` route as `POST`

Comment: @Michel; In an word I should change GET route to post. I did that and I got "The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again."

Answer (score 0):

You must add `csrf protection` when use form laravel.

You can read documentation laravel or you can read example in laravel 5.1  https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-protection